# Xcode: Two labels, one button

Tags: xcode, label

I am trying to change two labels in one click, without coding.

I don't want to set up it like:

```
IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
IBOutlet UILabel *label2;
```

I want to do that in the storyboard with the view controller (i.e., draw a line from the same object to two labels).

Comment: So, what's your question ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference two labels with the same outlet. If the issue is that you want the text of both labels to be updated when a single NSString value is set you can probably make it observable and on change set the text of both labels.